# XFS grow not working

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, xfs

So I have the following setup:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-9-177 ~]$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  80G  0 disk 
├─xvda1 202:1    0   6G  0 part /
└─xvda2 202:2    0   4G  0 part /data
```

All the tutorials I find say to use `xfs_growfs <mountpoint>` but that has no effect, nor has the `-d` option:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-9-177 ~]$ sudo xfs_growfs -d /
meta-data=/dev/xvda1             isize=256    agcount=4, agsize=393216 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=1572864, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=0
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data size unchanged, skipping
```

I should add that I am using:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-9-177 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-9-177 ~]$ xfs_info -V
xfs_info version 3.2.0-alpha2
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-9-177 ~]$ xfs_growfs -V
xfs_growfs version 3.2.0-alpha2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a 4GB xfs file system on a 4GB partition, so there is no work to do.

To overcome, enlarge the partition with parted then use xfs_growfs to expand the fs. You can use parted rm without losing data.

```
# umount /data
# parted
GNU Parted 3.1
Using /dev/xvda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) unit s
(parted) print
....
(parted) rm 2
(parted) mkpart
....
(parted) print
(parted) quit

# xfs_growfs /dev/xvda2
# mount /dev/xvda2 /data
```

Done. No need to update /etc/fstab as the partition numbers are the same.

Answer (score 14):

Before running `xfs_growfs`, you must resize the partition the filesystem sits on.

Give this one a go:

```
sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1
```

As per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html

Comment: Thats the most correct answer! was struggling for 2 days with Amazon AMI

Answer (score 3):

Before running xfs_growfs, Please do the following step first:

```
#growpart <devicenametobeextend> 

# growpart /dev/xvda 1                                                                                                                                                                   
CHANGED: partition=1 start=4096 old: size=31453151 end=31457247 new: size=41938911,end=41943007

#xfs_growfs -d /
```

[enter FYI for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqCXX.png)

Answer (score 2):

Many Servers by default won't have growpart utils So you can follow the below steps to do

1. Install `growpart utils` using package manager as per OS distribution below is for RPM/FEDORA based.

   `yum install cloud-utils-growpart`
2. Run the `growpart` command on the partition which has to change.

   `growpart /dev/xvda 1`
3. Finally run the `xfs_growfs` command.

   `xfs_growfs -d /dev/xvda1`